# Loop through an entry's fields and if the field type is "Categories" get that fields value/s

Tags: plugin-development

In my plugin I need to loop through an entry's fields and if that field is a field type of "Categories" use that entry field value/s.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
if(array_key_exists('byCategory', $filterAttributes))
{
  foreach ($entry->getFieldLayout()->getFields() as $key) 
  {
      $field = $key->getField();
      if($field->type == "Categories"){

         if(!$this->addFilterdCategories($field,$filterAttributes))
         {
             continue;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? It may help us to know what your starting point is.

Comment: @LindseyD I added code I have tried into the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer.

```
if(array_key_exists('byCategory', $filterAttributes))
{
  foreach ($entry->getFieldLayout()->getFields() as $key) 
  {
      $field = $key->getField();
      if($field->type == "Categories"){

         if(!$this->addFilterdCategories($entry[$field->handle],$filterAttributes))
         {
             continue;
         }
      }
   }
}
```